# Call UserControl method from a static method

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to do an ajax call in my asp.net application.
I have an aspx page and an ascx page.

In my Eccezioni.aspx first of all I declare my UserControl

```
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="UC" TagName="UserControlEccezioni" Src="~/Eccezioni.ascx" %>
 ....
 <div><UC:UserControlEccezioni runat="server" ID="ucEccezioni"/></div>
```

I have this ajax function:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Eccezioni.aspx/CheckExistingVariable",
                    data: '{var: "' + eccSplitt[i] + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function () {
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                    alert("ko");
                }
                });
```

in Eccezioni.aspx.cs I have the Webmethod:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static Boolean CheckExistingVariable(string var)
    {
        return ucEccezioni.CheckExistingVariable(var);
    }
```

The problem is that I can't access my ucEccezioni variable. 
what I can Do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access instance methods from a static method.  That's an iron-clad rule, and it means that you can't access non-static properties or methods of a control (or page) from a `WebMethod`, even if that `WebMethod`is embedded in the same control or page.

You have a number of options.  Here are several:

1. Rather than using a `WebMethod` in a web page, create a web service to do whatever `ucEccezioni.CheckExistingVariable` does, and call it via Ajax. This what most people recommend.
2. Make the method `ucEccezioni.CheckExistingVariable` a static method.  If you can do it - if `CheckExistingVariable` doesn't use any instance properties or methods - that would be a very simple way out of your dilemma. However, it's less elegant than option 1.
3. Use an `UpdatePanel`, if it's compatible with your overall design.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to Ann L's answer number 2, that didn't work for me. I still got an error saying "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method". I got around this by instantiating a new instance of my user control class and calling the static method.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static Boolean CheckExistingVariable(string var)
{
    ucEccezioniClass uc = new ucEccezioniClass();
    return uc.CheckExistingVariable(var);
}
```